# How to fix constraints not to show duplicated words?

Tags: ios, swift, label, tableview, constraints

My view controller looks weird on iPhone XR. I don't know why, but the words are duplicated and overwritten, but not on older versions.

Duplicated words:

[image: IMG:]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I implemented a search bar and have a basic table view of usernames.

Here are screenshots of my constraints for the label.

[image: Constraints]

[image: Constraints]

Swift:

```swift
class FindFriendsViewController: UIViewController {

var users = [User]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

var searchItem = [String]()
var searching = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.rowHeight = 71

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:)))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    UserService.usersExcludingCurrentUser { [unowned self] (users) in
        self.users = users

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
       }
    }
 }

extension FindFriendsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchItem.count
    } else {
        return users.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FindFriendsCell") as! FindFriendsCell

   // let user = users[indexPath.row]

    var usernamesArr = [String]()
    for user in users {
        usernamesArr.append(user.username)
    }

    if searching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchItem[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = usernamesArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self
        configure(cell: cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    return cell
}

func configure(cell: FindFriendsCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
    cell.followButton.isSelected = user.isFollowed
     }
  }

extension FindFriendsViewController: FindFriendsCellDelegate {
func didTapFollowButton(_ followButton: UIButton, on cell: FindFriendsCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return 
 }

    followButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let followee = users[indexPath.row]

    FollowService.setIsFollowing(!followee.isFollowed, fromCurrentUserTo: followee) { (success) in
        defer {
            followButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        guard success else { return }

        followee.isFollowed = !followee.isFollowed
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
      }
   }
}

extension FindFriendsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    var usernamesArr = [String]()
    for user in users {
        usernamesArr.append(user.username)
    }
    searchItem = usernamesArr.filter({$0.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
       searching = true
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your `FindFriendsCell` class in your post.

Comment: Because of `cell.textLabel`  replace `textLabel` with IBOutlet you have added for label

Comment: Oh wait yes never mind thank you both!

Comment: Also (separate question) but do you know why my search bar doesn't work based on my code? Same table view shows if I try searching for something - no individual or specific usernames

Comment: @Danny Use any one... Custom cell or native cell...remove anyone `cell.usernameLabel` or `cell.usernameLabel` .. **ONLY IN THE CELLFORROW ELSE PART**

Answer (score 0):

as @Prashant Tukadiya said, the `textLabel` is `UITableViewCell` Outlet and if you are using a custom cell u shouldn't use it. That is what you should do:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FindFriendsCell") as! FindFriendsCell

    var usernamesArr = [String]()
    for user in users {
        usernamesArr.append(user.username)
    }

    if searching {
        cell.usernameLabel.text = searchItem[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.usernameLabel.text = usernamesArr[indexPath.row].username
        cell.followButton.isSelected = usernamesArr[indexPath.row].isFollowed
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: value of type 'String' has no member 'username' and 'isFollowed'

Comment: obviously.... I'm assuming user object has a parameter called username from your code